# A strcat() implementation, how to realloc enough space to include both strings in C?

Tags: c, c-strings, strcat, function-definition

I am trying to implement the `strcat` function by myself, using pointers.

My pseudo-code is:

- receive 2 char pointers (which means 2 strings (= 2 char arrays)).
- create a copy of the `dest` array
- realloc() space of `dest` to be the sum of the sizes of `source string + dest string`, because I need the `dest` string to include in the end both of the strings.
- create a pointer that points to the first index of the `dest` string, this pointer will be returned as the function's return value.
- run 2 simple `while` loops on both `source` and `copy of dest` strings, and while doing this, copy all contents to the `dest`
- free all allocated pointers
- return the address that points to the first index of the `dest` string by return the created pointer that was created for this exact purpose.

So. I wrote this:

```
char *StrCat(char *dest, const char *src)
{
   size_t size = strlen(dest) + strlen(src) + 1;
   char *temp = (char *) malloc(strlen(dest) + 1);
   char *start = dest;
   dest = (char *) realloc(dest, size);
   strcpy(temp,dest);
   while (*src)
   {
       *dest = *src;
       src++;
       dest++;
   }
   while (*temp)
   {
       *dest = *temp;
       temp++;
       dest++;
   }
   *dest = '\0';
   free(temp);
   return start;
}

void strcatTest()
{
   char source[] = "this is source of cat";
   char dest4[100] = "this is dest of cat";
   StrCat(dest4,source);
   puts(dest4);
}
```

and I'm getting:
`realloc(): invalid pointer.`

I know there are a lot of working and better implementations of `strcat` around the internet and on `stackoverflow`, but my purpose here is to understand what did I do wrong and why I failed to create a working implementation.
What went wrong with my understanding of `starcat()`?

Comment: Your approach does not simulate the behavior of the standard function strcat.  Neither memory allocation should be within the function.

Comment: @VladfromMoscow the purpose of `strcat` is to "combine" 2 strings to one string, one after the another, and this is my purpose here as well.

Comment: strcat appends one string to the tail of another string. Neither allocation or reallocation of memory is present in the function.

Comment: Just drop the realloc entirely, you already know the necessary length `size_t size = strlen(dest) + strlen(src) + 1;` so malloc that amount, period.

Comment: but `strings` in `c` are `char arrays` which means they need to get a literal size before initializing OR to use dynamic allocation. In this case of `strcat` we don't know the needed size, because who knows what is the size of the strings we will receive. This is why I thought I have to use `realloc`, to define the size of the `dest` string as the sum of the sizes of the strings.

Comment: @NoobCoder Your function does not make a sense and moreover it is incorrect. It returns a pointer to already deallocated memory. As I said your function has nothing common with strcat.

Comment: @Lundin aren't we have to use `realloc` because the size of `dest` is already defined (in the `strcatTest` function, which means memory space already allocated?

Comment: You can't realloc `dest` because it wasn't dynamically allocated. You can only use realloc and free on dynamic heap memory. So you need to return a pointer to 3rd array in this case. Or alternatively forget all about dynamic memory and implement the function like strcat with caller-side allocation.

Comment: @VladfromMoscow This is why i'm here. I'm trying to understand why my function has nothing common with `strcat.` I went through `strcat` documentation, many of them, and thought I fully understand the purpose of the function and tried to implement it by myself.

Answer (score 0):

Beware, you can only use realloc on a pointer that has previously been alloc-ed, and not on a pointer to an automatic or static storage array.

So those lines are enough to cause the error:

```
char *StrCat(char *dest, const char *src)
{
...
   dest = (char *) realloc(dest, size);
...
   char dest4[100] = "this is dest of cat";
   StrCat(dest4,source);
```

This is the reason why the standard library does not try to reallocate...

Comment: Got you. So should I allocate dynamic memory with `malloc` instead of `realloct()?` Honestly, I don't even understand how the standard library uses and created `strcat()` without the need to use memory allocation? I mean it has to allocate memory because it combines to strings of unknown length to one string.

Comment: @NoobCoder: the standard `strcat` just trusts the programmer to make sure that there is enough memory in `dest` to copy there... If you want to return an allocated string combining 2 strings of unknows length, just allocate a new array and return it.

Comment: I just tried to do it using `dest = (char *) malloc(size);` instead of the realloc line. The output of the function is `"this is dest of cat"`

Answer (score 0):

From the C Standard (7.23.3.1 The strcat function)

> 2 The strcat function appends a copy of the string pointed to by s2
> (including the terminating null character) to the end of the string
> pointed to by s1. The initial character of s2 overwrites the null
> character at the end of s1. If copying takes place between objects
> that overlap, the behavior is undefined.

So within the standard C string function `strcat` neither allocation or reallocation memory is present. The destination character array shall be initially large enough to accommodate within itself one more string.

Take into account that you need to rename your function. Otherwise there will be a conflict between your function and the standard function.

The function definition can look the following way (without using any standard string function)

```
char * new_strcat( char *s1, const char *s2 )
{
    char *p = s1;

    while ( *p ) ++p;

    while ( ( *p++ = *s2++ ) );

    return s1;
}
```

Here is a demonstrative program.

```
#include <stdio.h>

char * new_strcat( char *s1, const char *s2 )
{
    char *p = s1;

    while ( *p ) ++p;

    while ( ( *p++ = *s2++ ) );

    return s1;
}

int main(void) 
{
    char s1[14] = "Hello ";
    const char *s2 = "World!";
    
    puts ( new_strcat( s1, s2 ) );
    
    return 0;
}
```

The program output is

```
Hello World!
```

If you want to write a new function that combines two strings creating a new character array (such a function is a different function compared with the standard string function `strcat`) then the function can be declared and defined the following way (in this implementation there is used the standard string function `strlen` though it can be written without using the function).

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

char * combine( const char *s1, const char *s2 )
{
    char *result = malloc( strlen( s1 ) + strlen( s2 ) + 1 );
    
    if ( result )
    {
        char *p = result;
        
        while ( *s1 ) *p++ = *s1++;

        while ( ( *p++ = *s2++ ) );
    }
    
    return result;
}

int main(void) 
{
    const char *s1 = "Hello ";
    const char *s2 = "World!";
    
    char *p = combine( s1, s2 );
    
    if ( p ) puts( p );
    
    free( p );
    
    return 0;
}
```

Again the program output is

```
Hello World!
```

As for your function then it is incorrect and does not make any sense. For example the user can pass to the function a character array with automatic storage duration. You may not reallocate it dynamically using `realloc`.

Or you at first assign the pointer `start` with the value of the pointer `dest` but then the memory pointed to by the pointer `dest` was reallocated. As a result the pointer `start` has an invalid value that is returned from the function.

```
char *start = dest;
dest = (char *) realloc(dest, size);

//...
return start;
```

Also you are trying to copy strings in the reverse order relative to each other, At first you are copying the string pointed to by the pointer `src` and then the string that initially was pointed to by the pointer `dest`. S0 you are not appending the second string to the tail of the first string.

Pay attention to your function declaration

```
char *StrCat(char *dest, const char *src);
```

The first parameter without the qualifier `const` means that the string pointed to by the pointer `dest` will be changed in place. So even the function declaration contradicts your function implementation because you are not changing the destination character array in place. You are trying to create a new character array.